VB6.EXE on Windows 11 is treated as an app from an unknown publisher
I have installed Visual Basic 6 on Windows 11 and want to use it from a script to compile several programs. The annoyance is that VB6.exe is treated as an app from an unknown publisher and every time I run it, I get prompt to ask me if I really want to run it.
Am I doing something wrong or this is just how it is?
I tried disabling UAC and it works, but that doesn't seem like the best idea (security wise) from what I understand.

Have you configured the executable with 'Run this program as an Administrator'?

This may help https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-install-visual-basic-6-on-windows-11-it-got/49cc9591-8463-424d-b77e-f174e08b76b6

In the comments of this question there is a link to a guide for installing VB6.  This may be of use to you, too.

@BrianMStafford I did try running it as an Administrator, but it makes no difference. I still get the prompt.

Thanks for the guides, I did follow a guide when installing it, but I do not know if the steps were exactly the same as in the guides you linked. I will have to reinstall and get back at you, but probably not today.

vb6 really is that old: they didn't sign their binaries back then. You probably should be updating to a more modern platform.

Which OS are we talking? We use VB6.exe command line compilation to compile our stuff  from within a self-written "CI" solution. The latter one is run "As Administrator" (and brings up UAC), but VB6 itself then doesn't raise an additional UAC prompt. Also: where is the VB6 executable located? That kind of message often shows up when the application is started from a network share.

I'm using Windows 11. VB6 executable is located in Program Files (x86).
